# Workflow rule/field update not firing when changes are made in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, workflowrule

For some reason, the workflow rule works as expected when changes are made on a standard page; but the workflow rule does not fire when I edit fields on the Visualforce Page, which means the problem does not come from the workflow rule criteria. When I make changes using the VF page, the changes are reflected, which means the DML operation was a success. Does anyone have a clue why the Workflow Rule does not fire when changes are made using VF page?

Comment: Visualforce pages that do DML via their VF controller are no different than DML done via standard UI, REST APIs, Data Loader, or other Apex DML.  DML occurs at the database layer and WFRs execute due to DML changes. Have you looked at the debug log?  There's not enough info here yet (use [edit]) to help you narrow this down

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, I'm not trained at looking at debug logs so I did not go that route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solid answer, but mysteriously I was able to update the field automatically using Flow Builder.